# Pong Game in Java

Tags: java

Im trying to make a simple pong game but i can't get my ball to move. I created 2 classes for ball and paddle, but i don't know how to call the methods for moving and bouncing inside the Pong class (it works ok if i launch if from Ball class).

Every time I try to call a method from `Ball` class i get this:

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method bounce(GOval) from the type Ball`

and if i try to quick fix that I just get another error from a different method until i get to one I can't change like `getHeight();`

How can i get the methods from `Ball` to work in `Pong`?
Should i move all my methods to `Pong` class and leave just the `makeBall();` inside `Ball`?

I dont have the code for bouncing the ball off the paddle or moving the paddle yet, but i'll work on that later. I just want the ball to start moving.

Ball:

```
package MyObjects;
import java.awt.Color;
import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;


public class Ball extends GraphicsProgram{
    private static final double BALL_SIZE=10;
    private static final double SPEED=1;
    private static final double PAUSE = 1000/48.0;
    private static boolean HIT = false;
    public double dx=SPEED;
    public double dy=1;

    public void run(){
        GOval ball = makeBall();
        add(ball);
        bounce(ball);
    }

    public static GOval makeBall(){
        GOval result = new GOval (20,20,BALL_SIZE,BALL_SIZE);
        result.setFilled(true);
        result.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        return result;

    }

    public void bounce(GOval ball){ 
        while(true){
            ball.move(dx,dy);
            if(ballHitBottom(ball) && dy>=0){
                dy*=-1;
                if(HIT==false)
                HIT=true;   
            }
            if(ballHitTop(ball) && dy<=0){
                if(HIT){
                dy*=-1;
                }
            }
            pause(PAUSE);
        }
    }

    private boolean ballHitBottom(GOval ball){
        double bottomY=ball.getY() + ball.getHeight();
        return bottomY >= getHeight();
    }

    private boolean ballHitTop(GOval ball){
        double topY=ball.getY();
        return topY <= 0;
    }
}
```

Paddle:

```
package MyObjects;

import java.awt.Color;

import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;

public class Paddle extends GraphicsProgram{
private static double HEIGHT=100;
private static double WIDTH=5;

public void run(){
    GRect paddle = makePaddle();
    add(paddle);
    paddle.sendToBack();
}

public static GRect makePaddle(){
    GRect result = new GRect(10,10,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    result.setFilled(true);
    result.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    return result;

}

}
```

Pong:

```
import MyObjects.Ball;
import MyObjects.Paddle;
import acm.graphics.GOval;
import acm.graphics.GRect;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;


public class Pong extends GraphicsProgram{
public void run(){
 GOval ball = Ball.makeBall();
 add(ball);
 GRect paddle = Paddle.makePaddle();
 add(paddle);

 Ball.bounce(ball);    // this won't work
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

I think we're going to need to see what GraphicsProgram does, to be honest. But I'd just declare a non-static instance of Ball:

```
public class Pong extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        // you'll need to add a constructor to the Ball class
        Ball base = new Ball();
        GOval ball = base.makeBall();
        add(ball);
        GRect paddle = Paddle.makePaddle();
        add(paddle);
        base.bounce(ball);
    }
}
```

Comment: well this kind of worked, the ball now moves, but starts in the top-right direction instead of bottom-right, sticks to the top of the window and slides off screen to the right (doesn't bounce).

I'm not sure how to show you what GraphicsProgram does, it is just a resurce pack we've been given at university classes and have been using it.

Comment: Your issues are likely to be around `GOval.move(dx, dy)`. I have no idea what that class is, or what it does. OR it could be an issue with your ball's starting position.

Comment: I don't know what else I can do about that, but here is this [GraphicsProgram](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html) thing i'm using.

And here is my program's export from eclipse if that's any help: 
[link](https://www.mediafire.com/?3zlzr8a4t8zl3t9)

Comment: Would it help if i wrote the entire thing inside Pong class? w/o using Ball and Paddle

Comment: You're not setting the x and y coords of the GOval you're adding to the GraphicsProgram - [link](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html#add%28acm.graphics.GObject%29)

Comment: i think the coords are set in `makeBall(); ` : 

`GOval result = new GOval (20,20,BALL_SIZE,BALL_SIZE);`

Comment: But that still isn't adding them to the GraphicsProgram. You need to set it when you call `GraphicsProgram.add(GOval, x, y)`.

Comment: I copied the ball and paddle code into Pong class and it's working, i'll finish the code and then try to split it into classes again

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to a non static method From Static reference  e.g.  `Ball.bounce(ball);`.
There are two way to resolve this

1. What you can do is change the signature of bounce method to static.

   ```
   public static void bounce(GOval ball){ 
   while(true){
       ball.move(dx,dy);
       if(ballHitBottom(ball) && dy>=0){
           dy*=-1;
           if(HIT==false)
           HIT=true;   
       }
       if(ballHitTop(ball) && dy<=0){
           if(HIT){
           dy*=-1;
           }
       }
       pause(PAUSE);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Call the bounce method like this. `ball.bounce();`and chage the bounce method to this.

   ```
   public void bounce(){ 
   while(true){
       this.move(dx,dy);
       if(ballHitBottom(this) && dy>=0){
           dy*=-1;
           if(HIT==false)
           HIT=true;   
       }
       if(ballHitTop(this) && dy<=0){
           if(HIT){
           dy*=-1;
           }
       }
       pause(PAUSE);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: //using 1.

if i hange bounce to static i need to also change ballHitBottom and Top to static, and then inside ballHitBottom i would need to change getHeight() to static and i cant do that


///using 2.

this doesnt seem to work either, dont know why yet, but there is  p roblem with this.move

Comment: then you have to create a `GOval ball` ball property in you ball class. and in your bounce method you could do `this.ball.move(dx,dy)`